# Caught exception: class org.jfrog.access.client.token.RestTokenClientImpl cannot be cast to class org.jfrog.access.client.token.GrpcTokenClientImpl

Tags: authentication, artifactory

Bitnami developer here. I'm getting the following error when starting artifactory 7.71.4:

```
2023-11-16T10:38:58.095Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:128 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-3] - Caught exception: class org.jfrog.access.client.token.RestTokenClientImpl cannot be cast to class org.jfrog.access.client.token.GrpcTokenClientImpl (org.jfrog.access.client.token.RestTokenClientImpl and org.jfrog.access.client.token.GrpcTokenClientImpl are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @173762d2)
```

It's not clear to me what causes this but it seems that there is an attempt to use a REST token client while the system expects a gRPC token client.

Without making any changes to the previous setup, I expected Artifactory to start up as normal. It's succeeding up to a point (It's possible to login) but then the token error appears.

Happy to provide you with more information if needed.

Comment: do you see any additional errors on the access-service.log?

Comment: Yes, this one:

2023-11-16T15:55:46.831Z [jfac ] [ERROR] [160eb64c4ab6858f] [.e.m.DefaultExceptionMapper:30] [http-nio-8040-exec-3] - Request GET /access/ui/crowd failed: Cannot invoke "java.util.function.Supplier.get()" because "this.cookieNameCache" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.function.Supplier.get()" because "this.cookieNameCache" is null

Comment: Is this the Pro version or OSS? I tried a new installation with the OSS on the same version and didn't get any issues.

Comment: It's the OSS version. Is there any pre-configuration of the token that needs to be set during installation? I'm using components Java 17, Node 18 and tomcat 9.0, they are supported right?

Comment: RT is coming bundled with Java 17, a specific version of Tomcat supported with it (which is 17), and node 16.18.1, have you changed anything prior to the installation? If yes, it can cause an issue.
did you change anything? Or any configuration in the system.yaml? Did you check the minimum resources required or open ports?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything, using tomcat 17, tried with Node 16 and 18. It's not a resources issue. Any hint at what the error could mean?

Comment: Also running the same processes:

/opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/metadata/bin/jf-metadata
/opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/router/bin/jf-router
/opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/observability/bin/jf-observability
/opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/integration/bin/jf-integration
node /opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/frontend/bin/server/dist/bundle.js /opt/bitnami/artifactory/app/frontend

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, the solution was to remove the serverUrl.override from the java options:

```
-Dartifactory.access.client.serverUrl.override
```

Together with adding product.home:

```
-Djf.product.home
```

Which we weren't setting correctly.